# Go Ethereum, txpool Namespace, empty responses

Tags: ethereum, json-rpc, go-ethereum

I have access to a Geth node running with the following options:

```
geth \
  --http \
  --http.addr 0.0.0.0 \
  --http.port 8545 \
  --http.api eth,net,web3,txpool \
  --http.corsdomain '*'
```

The node has been synced with the mode: `snap`.

Why do all my `txpool` API requests return "empty" responses?

- **txpool_content:** `curl http://IP:PORT -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "txpool_content", "params": [], "id": 0}'` -> `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":{"pending":{},"queued":{}}}`
- **txpool_inspect:** `curl http://IP:PORT -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "txpool_inspect", "params": [], "id": 0}'` -> `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":{"pending":{},"queued":{}}}`
- **txpool_status:**`curl http://IP:PORT -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "txpool_status", "params": [], "id": 0}'` -> `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":{"pending":"0x0","queued":"0x0"}}`

Thank you!

Comment: Are you submitting txs to the node? Have you tried submitting "bad txs" That is one way to fill the tx pool if you want to see somthing in the pending field.

Comment: No, I am not submitting any tx, but I am hoping to listen to txs on the network (txs in the MEMPOOL). Is it because my node has been synced in `snap` mode instead of `full` mode? Do I have to position myself as a miner and run the node with the `--mine` option? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: *txs in the MEMPOOL or TXPOOL

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> No, I am not submitting any tx

The mempool/tx-pool/tx-queue (usually mean the same thing with different terminologies across different Ethereum clients) will remain empty because there is nothing to process. Each node has its own pool and it isn't global. It is up to the consensus mechanism of the blockchain to include tx's into the next block from the respective validator/mining nodes.

Different clients have different ways of handling tx pools e.g. [OpenEthereum](https://openethereum.github.io/Transactions-Queue). But generally you will see the pending queue filled up (and probably never processed) if there is a bad nonce, or low gas price set. If the block time is large enough you can also see the pending tx's waiting to be mined.